# When do web browser decode compressed 206 chunk?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, web, gzip

When web browser decompressed (e.g. gzip) partial content (HTTP 206)?
Does it decode it after receiving all the chunks or it can decode with each chunk received?

If it doesn't decode the chunk we receive after 206 request, can we decompress it using JavaScript on the client?